# Dagger-Android @ActivityKey not found, how to create Sub components explicitly

Tags: android, dagger-2

In dagger 2.25.2 can not find `import dagger.android.ActivityKey` so i cannot add a subcomponent explicitly, instead of using `@ContributesInjector`, using `ApplicationModule`

```
@Module(subcomponents = [MainActivitySubComponent::class], includes = [DummyDependencyModule::class])
abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindInjectorFactory(builder: MainActivitySubComponent.Builder)
            : AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>

    @Module
    companion object DummyDependencyModule {
        @Provides
        fun provideDummyDependency(context: Context): DummyDependency {
            return DummyDependency(context)
        }
    }

}
```

Application Component is

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

MainActivity sub component is

```
@Subcomponent
interface MainActivitySubComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>()
}
```

I **created** an **ActivityKey** since it couldn't find the one from Dagger library

with error

> error: cannot find symbol,
>   @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
>   ^   symbol:   class ActivityKey   location: class ApplicationModule

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ActivityKey(val value: KClass<out Activity>)
```

And the error is

```
IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<cMainActivity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting the generated code i found that it's now used as `@ClassKey` in AppModule

```
@ClassKey(MainActivity::class)
abstract fun bindInjectorFactory(builder: MainActivitySubComponent.Builder)
        : AndroidInjector.Factory<*>
```

instead of

```
  @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindInjectorFactory(builder: MainActivitySubComponent.Builder)
            : AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>
```

and ClassKey code is

```
@Documented
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@MapKey
public @interface ClassKey {
  Class<?> value();
}
```